# Как создать sftp для уже имеющегося пользователя с ключом?

Tags: ssh, sftp

Уже есть пользователь UserAdmin с правами sudo, имеющий доступ к серверу по ssh- ключу. Как создать для этого же пользователя sftp с доступом к папке /home/web/site, желательно также с входом по ключу и как этот ключ указать в настройках sublime text для sftp-подключения?

Comment: `$ sshfs useradmin@сервер:/home/web/site /куда/надо/локально` и работайте с файлами в `/куда/надо/локально` из любого процесса, запущенного тем же пользователем, что выполнил упомянутую команду: хоть редактора любого, хоть «чёрта в ступе». главное — создавать ничего не надо (ну, кроме каталога) — «всё уже создано до нас».

Comment: а как это реализовать в текстовом редакторе sublime:

Comment: [google: sublime run shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34350912/4827341)